# Kio estas la diferenco inter bezoni kaj necesi?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, verbs, word-meaning, word-difference

Mi komprenas ke bezoni alvenis de la franca kaj necesi estas latina vorto. Ĉu gravas la diferenco inter la du vortoj?

Comment: Kiujn vortarojn vi kontrolis?

Comment: Mi ne kontrolis vortaron por tiu ĉi vorto. Mi nur uzas duolingon kaj lernun. En la angla la du vortoj signifas "to need" kaj mi vidas ke oni uzas la du vortojn. Mi ne komprenis kiel la signifo de la du vortoj diferencas.

Comment: Mi kredas ke la respondo al via demando estas en PIV (www.vortaro.net).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La diferenco estas, ke "necesi" signifas "esti necesa", kaj "bezoni" signifas "suferi pro manko de [io necesa]" aŭ "ne povi agi sen [io]". Do "bezoni" uziĝas kiel la hispana "*necesitar*" (angle "*to need*"), dum "necesi" estas pli simila al la hispana "*ser necesario*" (angle "*to be necessary*").

Ekzemploj:

Mi bezonas manĝaĵon. (*Necesito comida / I need food*)
Manĝaĵo necesas por mi (*La comida es necesaria para mí / Food is necessary for me*)
Ni ne bezonas tiom da sukero! (*¡No necesitamos tanto azúcar! / We don't need that much sugar!*)
Tiom da sukero ne necesas! (*¡Tanto azúcar no es necesario! / That much sugar is not necessary!*)
Por fari panon, mi bezonas fornon. (*Para hacer pan, necesito un horno / To make bread, I need an oven*)
Forno necesas por fari panon (*Un horno es necesario para hacer pan / An oven is needed for making bread*)

Comment: Dankon Kristan, tiu cxi es la respondo de mia demando.  La signifo ne estas tiel granda sed gravas. Mi komprenas nun.

Answer (score 5):

Unu grava diferenco estas ke *bezoni* baze estas transitiva verbo kaj *necesa* baze estas adjektivo. Tial se oni uzas *necesi* kiel verbon ĝi estus netransitiva. Tio estas malkiel la hispana kaj kataluna laŭ mia kompreno, ĉar en tiuj lingvoj *necessitar* estas pli kiel *bezoni* ol *necesi*.

> Necessito una paraigua [katalune] = Mi bezonas ombrelon [esperante]
>
> Cal menjar bé [katalune] = Necesas manĝi bone [esperante]

Tamen mi supozas ke oni povus konstrui la signifon de *necesa* per la radiko *bezon-*, do eble oni povus diri ke ĝi estas superflua. Ekzemple:

> Necesas manĝi fruktojn ĉiutage ≈ Bezonatas / bezoniĝas manĝi fruktojn ĉiutage

La difino de *necesa* en [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#necesa) estas *tre bezonata*, do eble *necesa* simple estas pli forta versio de *bezonata*.

Comment: Minus unu pro la strangegaj vortoj "bezonatas" kaj  "bezoniĝas".

Comment: @TomasoAlexander ĉu vi vere malsupren voĉdonis pro tiuj vortoj? Ho ve. Mi ne intencis rekomendi uzi ilin, ĝi estis nur parto de la ekzemplo pri kiel la du vortoj malsamas. Eble mi devus pli klare skribi tion. Tamen la du vortoj ja uzatas kaj uziĝas, simple serĉu en Tekstaro kaj Guglo por ekzemploj.

Comment: "La difino de necesa en PIV estas tre bezonata, do eble necesa simple estas pli forta versio de bezonata." Do, mi komprenas kun tiu cxi ekspliko ke bezono estas tre necesa kaj neceso estas tre, tre necesa...  Tre estas pli forta versio.  Mi komparis la du vortojn en PIV kaj mi ne vidis grandan diferon en la difino. @TomasoAlexander diras ke estas difero inter la du vortoj.  Dankon pro via pacienco.  Mi nur volas kompreni.

Answer (score 1):

Mi bezonas panon.

Pano necesas por vivi. (Pano estas necesa por vivi.)

Comment: Mi ne komprenas tiun ĉi eksemplon. Mi parolas la hispanan, la francan kaj la anglan, sed tiu ĉi ne estas klara al mi. ĉu oni povas diri, "Pano estas bezonata por vivi?"

Comment: Tio estas gxenerala demando pri gramatiko. Jes, se oni povas diri "Mi X-as Y-on" oni ankaux povas diri "Y estas X-ata" (de mi).

Comment: Gxi ne estas gxeneral demando pri gramatiko.  Estas demando pri signifo.  Mi ekkomprenas ke la signifo de bezoni kaj necesi samas, sed malsamas la uzo?

Comment: Tiu kiu komprenas komprenas la gramatikon, ja scias ke "Mi bezonas panon" libere transformigxas al "Pano estas bezonata." Tial mi komentis te temas pri generala demando pri gramatiko. Fakte la signifoj de bezoni kaj necesi estas malsamaj - kiel mi provis montri per ekzemplo - kaj kiel Neil tre bone respondis en la unuaj alineoj de sia respondo.